# How can i extract data from a Powershell command result?

Tags: azure, powershell

I run the command az command list ... in Powershell

Here is the result:

```
                {
            "cost": 0.0,
            "interval": "0:30:00",
            "namespace": "Microsoft.NetApp/netAppAccounts/capacityPools/volumes",
            "resourceregion": "eastus",
            "timespan": "2022-06-01T02:35:31Z/2022-06-01T03:35:31Z",
            "value": [
            {
            "displayDescription": "Logical size of the volume (used bytes)",
            "errorCode": "Success",
            "id": ,
            "name": {
            "localizedValue": "Volume Consumed Size",
            "value": "VolumeLogicalSize"
            },
            "resourceGroup": ,
            "timeseries": [
            {
            "data": [
            {
            "average": 0.08333333,
            "count": null,
            "maximum": null,
            "minimum": null,
            "timeStamp": "2022-06-01T02:35:00+00:00",
            "total": null
            },
            {
            "average": 0.1678524,
            "count": null,
            "maximum": null,
            "minimum": null,
            "timeStamp": "2022-06-01T03:05:00+00:00",
            "total": null
            }
            ],
            "metadatavalues": []
            }
            ],
            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
            "unit": "Bytes"
            }
            ]
            }
```

How can i extract the array "data" in the output response which has average of 0.08 and 0.16  and be able to traverse it in Powershell ?

Comment: You should be able to pipe to ConvertFrom-Json or use the powershell equivalent command which is what I would recommend.

Comment: See: [`PowerShell Json get value`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PowerShell+json+get+value)